# InvalidProgramException using Entity

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, exception

I keep getting an InvalidProgramException trying to grab data through the entity framework.

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var utrs = from u in db.users_to_roles
               select u; // utrs.Count() > 1 at this point. So, there IS data!

    users_to_roles utr = utrs.FirstOrDefault(); // InvalidProgramException!
    utrs.GetEnumerator(); // InvalidProgramException!
    utrs.ToList(); // InvalidProgramException!
}
```

The table is simple:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_to_roles` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `roleid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fkuserid` (`userid`),
  KEY `FK22FCE45052C7D0B5` (`roleid`),
)
```

I don't have this problem with other tables. What am I missing?

Exception: **System.InvalidProgramException - "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program."**

Stack Trace:

```
 at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.users_to_roles_026CF8D248576FA69379B3C621F372FAF9B6F2E4794C8490AE27BABE54609FF1.set_id(Decimal )
       at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
       at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
       at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
       at Users.Lib.DAOs.Mysql.MysqlUserDAO.RemoveRoleFromUser(String email, String roleName) in C:\Work\Users.Lib\DAOs\Mysql\MysqlUserDAO.cs:line 242
```

**Edit**

Solution, thanks to @Quintin below. The 'id' column in my entities was mapped to a decimal instead of an Int64. Not sure how it got this way, but problem is solved!

Comment: Please post detailed information about the exception and in particular its innerException

Comment: unfortunately, the inner exception is null. See stack trace posted above.

Comment: Ok didnt see that one coming, whats the exception itself?

Comment: Do any of your other tables have a data type of bigint(20) that is unsigned?.. I suspect a mapping issue that is freaking out the jit.

Comment: Thanks @Quintin Robinson, it was a mapping issue. One of the items got mapped to a decimal instead of Int64. I never thought to look there, because I assumed it would just map correctly in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you encountered a bug in EF, please see: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/620031/invalidprogramexception-using-entityframework-poco-template-table-w-decimal-primary-key#

Comment: Possibly related. The original issue is because of the incorrect mapping from long to decimal. But, if I map from long to int (my keys aren't big enough yet), I don't get the exception. So, looks like it's directly related to the primary key/decimal combination.